# How can I get the list of column fast in R for regression?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many columns, and I want to do a regression.

Currently, I have to type:

```
lm (col3 ~ col4 + col5 + col6 ... + col20)
```

It is not very convenient. Is there a faster way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We subset the dataset by selecting the columns that are needed in the regression formula and use `.` on the RHS of `~` to specify all the columns that are not the dependent variable ('col3').

```
lm(col3~., subset(df1, select=col3:col20))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 25*40, replace=TRUE), ncol=25))
colnames(df1) <- paste0('col', 1:25)
```